# No timezones for any location

Tags: macbook-pro, timezone

I cannot set any timezone on my Mac. If I go to Date & Time and pick any location I always get empty timezone.

[image: Data&Time with timezone]

Running:  sudo systemsetup -listtimezones
returns
Time Zones:

When I try to set timezone from command line I go info about invalid timezone.
What is interesting:
/etc/localtime -> /var/db/timezone/zoneinfo/Europe/Warsaw

Still time is not correct for Warsaw timezone.
I tried set automatically and not - nothing helps. (I did reboot laptop)
I suspect there is some cache for timezones which is corrupted, but I don't know how to rebuild it.

System Version: macOS 10.15.6 (19G2021)
Kernel Version: Darwin 19.6.0

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Have you allowed "Time Zone & System Customization" to use your location? Open System Preferences>Security & Privacy>Privacy, select Location Services and press the "Details..." button next to System Services to find out.

Comment: Yes it's enabled. Even when I put proper location manually there is no timezone. In fact if I select any location - still no time zone.
I think that  it's because systemsetup -listtimezones returns empty list for some reason.

Comment: Yes, `systemsetup -listtimezones` should return a list of time zones. Can you check if the directory `/private/var/db/timezone` exists on your Mac? It should contain a symlink to `/var/db/timezone/tz/2020d.1.0/icutz`, a symlink to `/var/db/timezone/tz/2020d.1.0`, a symlink to `/var/db/timezone/tz/2020d.1.0/zoneinfo` and a subfolder named `tz`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are encountering the same issue as [Time in GMT or Missing Time Zones in systemsetup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405697/time-in-gmt-or-missing-time-zones-in-systemsetup). I posted [a solution there](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/414829/408090). In my case, I didn't even have the visual representation of the timezone on the map.